# Use "mysql_fetch_row" to retrieve results from database and insert into array using PHP and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, mysqli

I need to retrieve data from several rows and then insert the results into an enumerated array so then I can use a "for" loop to echo it...

I have this (I already connected to the database):

```
$genres_sql = 'SELECT genreID FROM genres WHERE imdbID = ?';
if ($stmt->prepare($genres_sql)) {
    // bind the query parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $movieid);
    // bind the results to variables
    $stmt->bind_result($genre);
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Here I get the first result (row) into a variable. But I need to insert it into an enumerated array so the I can echo each result using this:

```
if (!empty($genre)) {
for ($i = 0; $i + 1 < count($genre); $i++)
{
    echo $genre[$i].', '; 
}
echo $genre[$i];
}
```

This will echo: `$genre[0], $genre[1], $genre[2],` and so on until the last one.

I know that `mysql_fetch_row` can do the work, but I'm new to programming so I need a very detailed explanation..
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop using the `MySQLi_Statement::fetch` method:

```
$stmt->bind_result($genre);
$stmt->execute();
$genres = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $genres[] = $genre;
}
```

Basically `fetch` provides an iterator that the `while` can use to iterate through each result. The variables in `bind_result` (in this case `$genre`) are reassigned with each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% familiar with mysqli but I've played with a lot of pgsql commands doing this sort of thing and i think what your looking for is [mysqli-result->fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). This will produce an associative array that you can loop over pretty easily like so:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ($row["genre"]);
}
```

**EDIT:** [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak) has linked to better explanation than i have in the comments for this answer.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to mix "fetch_assoc" with "execute".  The former needs a "result set" object, as returned by "query", whilst the latter works with a "statement" object.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627197/mixing-phps-mysqli-data-access-functions, where I've tried to explorer this difference more fully

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to the question, but if you want to print out an array as a comma-separated list, it's better to use the [implode](http://www.php.net/implode) command than a for loop:

```
//Replaces the for loop in the question
echo implode(', ', $genre);
```

...except that there's no comma after the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete @Mykroft reply, if you really just want an enumerated array just use $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM), although and associative array is much simple to use in most situations.