# How can i get all the values in the query?

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "titan3d");


if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sdate = "";
$stime = "";

if(isset($_POST['sdate']))
 {
  $sdate = $_POST["sdate"];
 }
if(isset($_POST['stime']))
 {
  $stime = $_POST["stime"];
 } 


$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT bookedseat FROM bookings WHERE sdate = ? AND stime = ?");{


    $statement->bind_param("si", $sdate, $stime);


    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        trigger_error('Error executing MySQL query: ' . $statement->error);
    }


    $statement->bind_result($book);


    $statement->fetch();

    printf($book);
 

 //header('Location: http://localhost/My%20Project/seats.html');


    $statement->close();
}


$mysqli->close();

?>
```

This is my php file made to get the data from a form and make a query and then display the results.

When executed,the php works perfectly.

But it only displays the first value in the query.

Why is it?

How can I display all the values in my query?

Comment: Iterate over the result set or just use the fetch all for mysqli

Comment: Php code is not a runnable snippet.  When you post your php code block, highlight the text, then press `Ctrl + K` to format it as a code block.  Please use Object-oriented or Procedural `mysqli_` functions in your code (not both).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use "mysql\_fetch\_row" to retrieve results from database and insert into array using PHP and mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627036/use-mysql-fetch-row-to-retrieve-results-from-database-and-insert-into-array-us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$stmt->fetch()` in a while loop, you can then iterate over each the returned row.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // $book will have the value of bookedseat for the current row
}
```

Comment: $seats = array();
 while ($statement->fetch()) {
  $seats[] = $book;
 }
  
 
    print_r($seats);